# How to handle SIGUSR1 in python

Tags: python-2.7, signals

```
import os  
import signal  
from time import sleep  

child=[]

for i in range(2):
    pid = os.fork()
    if pid == 0:
        child=[]
        print 'child start,pid',os.getpid()
        break
    else:
        child.append(pid)

if(child):
    def onsig1(a,b):
        print 'onsig1->',a

    signal.signal(signal.SIGCHLD,onsig1)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1,onsig1)

    try:
        print os.getpid(),' start wait...',str(child)
        while True:
            pid, stat = os.wait()
            print '--->',pid,stat
    except Exception as e:
        print 'error -->',str(e)
else:
    def onsig2(a,b):
        print 'onsig2->',a
    signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR2,onsig2)
    while True:
        sleep(10)
        print os.getpid(),'say ...'
```

12500  start wait... [12501, 12502]
When I used 'kill -USR2  12501' , I got 'onsig2->12' and the two child process are alive. I understand this.
But when I used 'kill -USR1 12500',I got 'onsig1->10',but the father process will dead.
I don't understand why.

Comment: Do you ever get output from `error -->`?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I got "error --> [Errno 4] Interrupted system call"  when 'kill -USR1 12500'

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I forgot wrap try block into while

```
while True:
    try:
        print os.getpid(),' start wait...',str(child)
        while True:
            pid, stat = os.wait()
            print '--->',pid,stat
    except Exception as e:
        print 'error -->',str(e)
```